# Swift Sprite Kit Audio API instead of AVFoundation?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, avfoundation, ios8

I'm making a game with `Swift` and `Sprite Kit`.

I would like to add *background music* and *sound effects*.

The "classic" way is to use `AVFoundation`, but this does not seem to have new Swift APIs, only `Objective C` ones.

Is there a new **modern swift** sound API I can use with Sprite Kit easily?

Comment: Nope. AVFoundation is, like any other Objective-C framework, readily available from Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No frameworks have new Swift APIs in iOS 8 or OS X Yosemite. All Objective-C frameworks are automatically bridged to Swift, and those include both SpriteKit and AVFoundation.

If you're looking for a quick high-level alternative to the more detailed AVFoundation APIs for adding sounds and music to your game, look no further than SpriteKit itself. (Regardless of whether you use Swift or Objective-C.)

`SKAction` provides a [`playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKAction/playSoundFileNamed%3awaitForCompletion%3a) action. Pass `false` for the second parameter to play sound effects, or pass `true` and make a repeating action to loop music.